# macro incorporating \addcontentsline and fancyhdr package with unique identification numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, fancyhdr

I have several documents that have identification numbers inputted inside user-defined macros. The macros put the identification numbers on the top of the document pages using the `fancyhdr` package. I would like to add a table of contents to the master document to easily navigate through all of the subdocuments (each with multiple pages and unique identification numbers). Additionally, there are three subdocuments for each identification number. I currently have the following code to define these macros:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

%Users enter \pid{NUMBERS}
%I want the command to place the NUMBERS on the top left of each page and to add a contents line the first (and only the first) time it is called for each subject
\newcommand{\pid}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\pid}[1]{\lhead{\texttt{Participant ID: }##1}}%
    \lhead{\texttt{Participant ID: }#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}

%User types \scneario{NAME} here
%I want this to display the scenario as a subsection the first (and only the first) time it is called *for each unique identification number*
\newcommand{\scenario}[1]{%
    \rhead{\texttt{Scenario: }#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\pid{111}
\scenario{Scen1}
Some text.\\
Some more text.\\

\pid{111}
\scenario{Scen2}
Some text.\\
Some more text.\\

\newpage

\pid{222}
\scenario{Scen1}
Some text.\\
Some more text.\\

\newpage

\pid{222}
\scenario{Scen2}
Some text.\\
Some more text.\\

\end{document}
```

In my document each of these is actually a `\input{document.tex}`. Currently neither command works.

Comment: You're not using `\pagestyle{fancy}` at all. And use empty lines between text lines like `Some text.`,not `\\`. The `\renewcommand{\pid}{}` is wrong in my point of view

Comment: For the `\scenario` macro, you could check for the existence of a macro which has the current pid as part of its name, and if there is none define it and execute the stuff which should be executed the first time it is used.

Comment: Why do you use `\addcontentsline` but don't start a new section btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the behaviour you want?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pid}[1]{%
    \lhead{\texttt{Participant ID: }#1}% Set the head anyway
    \ifcsname pid#1\endcsname% check existence of a macro called 'pid#1'
    \else% if there is none
    \expandafter\gdef\csname pid#1\endcsname{}% define a macro with that name
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}% add the contentsline
    \fi%
    \gdef\cur@pid{#1}% define a global macro containing the current pid
}
\newcommand{\scenario}[1]{%
    \rhead{\texttt{Scenario: }#1}%
    \ifcsname\cur@pid @scenario#1\endcsname% I added a #1 here so the scenario name is also considered in the check
    \else%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname\cur@pid @scenario#1\endcsname{}% I added a #1 here
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pid{111}
\scenario{Scen1}
\scenario{Scen1}
\lipsum[1]

\pid{111}
\scenario{Scen2}
\scenario{Scen2}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\pid{222}
\scenario{Scen1}
\scenario{Scen1}
\lipsum[1]

\pid{222}
\scenario{Scen2}
\scenario{Scen2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This results in the following ToC:
[image]

Note that this fails if you use `\scenario` prior to the first usage of `\pid`.

EDIT: Changed the behaviour of `\scenario`, now it puts the scenario into the toc unless the same combination of `\pid` and `\scenario`-name was already encountered.

Comment: This is great and *almost* 100% what I need. The only problem is that it fails to add additional scenarios to the TOC. I would like Scen2 to be in the table on contents under each ID as well.

Quick thank-you for commenting your code. Helps me to learn LaTeX!

Comment: @AdamK sorry for this issue, it was my understanding, that you wanted this behaviour... I'll edit and fix it.

Comment: @AdamK please also note, that this approach does not put a scenario in another `\pid`-section level then the latest one, if that's something you wanted. So inserting a `\pid{111}\scenario{Scen3}` at the end of the document as it is in my MWE now, would insert 'Scen3' into the ToC below of '222'.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and again for commenting out your changes.

Comment: @AdamK then how about accepting it? :)

Comment: Done! (Also new to Stack Exchange). Thanks!